# Maven plugin as dependency in multi-module project

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'm having a problem with [a multi-module project](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java/tree/b29ea92145cb043e7be1d0f2ed0c860106f578fd) where one of the modules is an annotation-based maven-plugin: https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java/

Basically, `mvn compile` fails the first time and then succeeds when I do a second `mvn compile`.

It also works OK from clean if I do

```
mvn -pl generator compile
mvn compile
```

**I'd like the build to succeed in one go so that I can do a build and release of all modules.**

Comment: feel free to look at the source (linked above) :-) AFAIK, the plugin is packaged correctly but I don't know what you mean by "is netlib set as pom in the same attribute"

Comment: I can't get it to build even after manually installing jlapack (I tweaked maven-compiler-plugin settings to add the interface mojo and your AbstractNetlibGenerator so it won't use jlapack javadoc so it builds but some tests keep failing but if I skip them it seems to work - after all this tweaking), quick 'silly'question..since you use generator on netlib as a build plugin have you tried building the generator plugin first and then the whole project?

Comment: I didn't try that, but I would expect it would break sonatype releases, wouldn't it? Sorry it didn't work... I'm in the middle of dev so probably in an inconsistent state.

Comment: @RafaelOltra I updated the link to point to a new branch which should compile (but only if the plugin is compiled and installed separately): `mvn install -pl generator ; mvn compile`. That will break sonatype releasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a quick look at your project and found, that the "generator" plugin is part of the multimodule project **and** it is used (with the same version) within this project. This is not a legal use! You have to provide all required plugins from outside the reactor!

The reason for this is, that maven tries to fill the reactor and determine all required plugins beforehand. Then it starts the build. Maven cannot perform this, if the generator plugin is part of the project.

Stephen Connolly wrote about this in a blog post: [Maven and the "Install" Hack](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/maven-and-install-hack).

hth,
- martin

Comment: that's a great shame because my project is clearly a valid use case for plugins with the same reactor.

Comment: same. need to write my own build system then XD

Comment: the way to get your dynamically generated plugin to get triggered in the reactor is to add an extra scope 'provided' dependency in the module using your plugin. (also mvn -am)

<plugin>
 <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
          <artifactId>your plugin dependency</artifactId>
              </dependency>
              </dependencies>
   </plugin>
...</build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>your plugin dependency</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

Answer (score 0):

(I'm placing this as an answer because it won't fit on the comments area)

Well I downloaded the 11fe0f5 revision from Github and tried mvn clean install on the parent/root folder to see what would happen and I got this error:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.444s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jun 24 20:00:30 BRT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/350M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'interface' in plugin org.netlib:generator:1.0-SNAPSHOT among available goals -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoNotFoundException
```

Which led me to question if the interface goal really existed in the generator plugin and if it's goal descriptor was being generated..
So looking at the generator module pom.xml I couldn't find any maven-plugin configuration in order to generate a plugin module, so I changed your maven-plugin-plugin configurations to:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>descriptor</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

and that added the interface goal to the generator plugin and I'm now able to install from the root folder just fine.

mvn clean install partial output:

```
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ netlib ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\ebook\netlib-java-11fe0f502496276be5536003eaacbde363317c
b1\netlib\target\netlib-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ netlib ---
[INFO] Installing C:\ebook\netlib-java-11fe0f502496276be5536003eaacbde363317cb1\
netlib\target\netlib-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\oltra01\.m2\repository\org\net
lib\netlib\1.0-SNAPSHOT\netlib-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\ebook\netlib-java-11fe0f502496276be5536003eaacbde363317cb1\
netlib\pom.xml to C:\Users\oltra01\.m2\repository\org\netlib\netlib\1.0-SNAPSHOT
\netlib-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] parent ............................................ SUCCESS [0.478s]
[INFO] generator ......................................... SUCCESS [6.172s]
[INFO] netlib ............................................ SUCCESS [1:05.310s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:12.105s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jun 24 19:55:08 BRT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/491M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What maven commands/goals are you using to get the error in your question? Have you tried removing your whole repository? (maybe you've got a messed up version of generator installed there)

Comment: That's weird, I don't need the executor goal. I'll try this later tonight to see if by adding it, everything builds in one pass.

Comment: you mean the descriptor goal?

Comment: ok, this is weird. Now that I add the `execution` to run the `descriptor` goal, I get `[ERROR] Could not find goal 'interface'` in the first pass and it works in the second pass. So, still not fixed, but this might be a hint.

Comment: Well, the reason I had to add the mojo-descriptor execution to the maven-plugin-plugin (in the pom for generator) is because no plugin description was being generated and hence when executing the generator plugin the goal interface could not be found (same error that you got now) but after adding that everything worked fine on the clean install from the root, are you sure you changed the pom as I've mentioned? here's the entire file https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5862561

Comment: thanks again @Rafael, I've definitely [done what you've said](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java/tree/b29ea92145cb043e7be1d0f2ed0c860106f578fd) and it still takes two passes. Try deleting your cache and running `mvn clean` before doing a `mvn compile` to confirm what I'm seeing.